# How to create Insert with Select query in a variables using SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to create an insert with select query in a variables using SQL Server?

Here for example:

```
DECLARE @sqlCommand nvarchar(MAX)
DECLARE @odbname varchar(30)
DECLARE @m VARCHAR(20)
DECLARE @id VARCHAR(20)
DECLARE @br VARCHAR(30)
DECLARE @ndbname VARCHAR(30)

SET @ndbname='databasename'
SET @id = 2

SET @odbname = 'olddatabasename'
SET @br = 2

SET @m = 9

DECLARE @insert VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @insert = 'INSERT INTO'+ @ndbname+'.[pm]([pmId],[pmCode],[pmName])'  

EXEC (@insert)

SET @sqlCommand = 'SELECT @id AS spID,[spCode],[spName] `enter code here`FROM' + @0dbname+'.[sp] where spbID = @br and spID = @m'

EXECUTE sp_executesql @sqlCommand, N'@br nvarchar(75),@m nvarchar(75),@id VARCHAR(20)',@br = @br,@m=@m,@id=@id
```

Actually I needed a select query executed in insert query ie, selected data inserted in to another database table

Comment: The syntax is: insert into **table_name1** select col_names from **table_name2**. In this case, the structure of that table1 and selected columns structure from table2 should be same.

Comment: sorry, i cannot get .please explan more...

Comment: Can you acess both database from query window
then you can use

INsert into  TODBname.SchemaName.TableName
Select columns list from FROMDBname.SchemaName.TableName

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SET @insert='INSERT INTO'+ @ndbname+'.[pm]([pmId],[pmCode],[pmName])'  
SET @sqlCommand = @insert + ' ' +'SELECT @id AS spID,[spCode],[spName] `enter code here`FROM' + @0dbname+'.[sp] where spbID = @br and spID = @m'
EXECUTE sp_executesql @sqlCommand, N'@br nvarchar(75),@m nvarchar(75),@id VARCHAR(20)',@br = @br,@m=@m,@id=@id
```

Comment: This is really working fine? Missing spaces, invalid variable name "@0dbname"... schema names... ?

Comment: Just a space, it is not very important in this case.

Comment: Did you even check this out? @user2728653 seems to be happy, but I cannot imagine that this is working at all... nvm and Happy Coding!

Comment: I think user2728653 understand that INSERT and SELECT must be one after other in order to insert what he needed. @Sankar Raj later give a good explanation, and only example needed to be posted.

Comment: @IlyaOdintsov, Your "example" produces *wrong* code. At least the wrong three-part-qualified name (`databasename.schemaname.tablename`) is a major flaw... But we don't have to be that picky. OP is happy and so should be we :-)

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few flaws:

- You try to execute the INSERT alone
- If you state a dbName, you must specify the schema (is it "dbo"?)
- You're letting out spaces

If you change to this

```
SET @insert='INSERT INTO'+ @ndbname+'.[pm]([pmId],[pmCode],[pmName])'  
SET @sqlCommand = @insert + ' SELECT @id AS spID,[spCode],[spName] `enter code here`FROM' + @odbname+'.[sp] where spbID = @br and spID = @m'
PRINT @sqlCommand
```

You'll get this:

```
INSERT INTOdatabasename.[pm]([pmId],[pmCode],[pmName]) SELECT @id AS spID,[spCode],[spName] `enter code here`FROMolddatabasename.[sp] where spbID = @br and spID = @m
```

But it should be something like this

```
INSERT INTO databasename.[schema].[pm]([pmId],[pmCode],[pmName]) 
SELECT @id,[spCode],[spName] 
FROM olddatabasename.[schema].[sp] 
where spbID = @br and spID = @m
```

General hints:

- Don't use dynamic SQL if you don't need it
- If you build dynamic sql don't try to execute it. Rather print it, copy it to a query window and analyze if it is OK